# Attempted import error: 'FaBars' is not exported from 'react-icons/fa'

Tags: node.js, reactjs

After using the command `npm install react-icons`, `import { FaBeer } from 'react-icons/fa'` in my script is not working and the error message is `Attempted import error: 'FaBars' is not exported from 'react-icons/fa'.`
The script was working previously and all of sudden, it stops working for no reasons. I then tried to download the previous commit in gitlab (it must be working before), and still it is not working. The `index.js` in the `/node_moudles/react-icons/fa/index.js` is weird as it is now different from the old version. It's nearly emoty.
[node_modules/react-icons/fa/index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWSTS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow! I don't have the entire picture of your problem yet but it's probably a dependency issue. Can you try deleting node_modules and your package-lock.json. I personally use rimraf to make the process easier. You can follow these steps and let's see how it goes.

1. Open up your terminal and type `npm install -g rimraf`.
2. Then go to your project directory and run this `rimraf node_modules package-lock.json`.
3. Once deleted, run `npm install` to get a fresh install of your dependencies.

Try running your app again to see if that solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I also noticed that in your post, the error is pointing to a different icon  'FaBars' instead of FaBeer which you're importing. Kindly edit if it's a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The right path is (  import { FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa' ), because the fa icon and others are  in a folder called  ( react-icons) not react..

Change the path to the above mentioned path..

For further explanation, If you want to see the path for yourself, click on node_modules, look for the react folder and the react-icons folder..    When you click on the react folder, you wont see icons in it, but if you click on the react-icons folder, you will see all the icons in it..  That means you import path should be ( import { FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa' ).